# Assert button disabled on click with Protractor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

We have a submission button that becomes disabled while waiting for the operation to complete. In this case, the operation completes by navigating to the `/dashboard` page.

We would like to assert this 'disabled while pending' behaviour in our end-to-end Protractor tests:

```
it('should disable button after submission', function(){
  page.usernameTextBox.sendKeys(username);
  page.passwordTextBox.sendKeys('password1');
  page.signInButton.click();
  expect(page.signInButton.getAttribute('disabled')).toContain('true');
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/dashboard');
});
```

The assertion on the `disabled` attribute fails as the next page has already loaded. This is because Protractor waits for the operation to complete before running the assertion - i.e. its not being missed due to a race condition - Protractor actually has it synchronised so that the assertion will not be run until the operation completes.

How can I test the above behaviour?

Comment: woud you post the error output? just for testing purpose: could you try replacing `page.signInButton` with it's actual selector element(by.someSelector('foo'))

Answer (score 1):

**Now try this:** expect(page.signInButton.isEnabled().toBe(false));

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty much from the stone ages of web development, but since I still found it in 2018, I assume others will too, and I'm going to answer it anyway for the sake of correct information.

So, asserting your button has a name, you could do something like this with a current version of protractor:

```
expect(element(by.name('loginButton')).isEnabled()).toBeFalsy();
```